# is being at a highly reputable university the only way to progress in academia

Tags: phd, community

I'm in my 4th year of my phd at a fairly small and less known university (in Europe) where I also did my bachelors and masters. I submitted 6 more papers to the top conference in the field and every one of them got in immediately. Besides this, a lot of my papers had lots of press attention. Many people in our group are more focused on quantity so they also collaborate with a people from other universities who have the same mind set. For some reason, I'm not so interested in this approach and I'm a real quality freak and therefore do almost everything myself. But my advisors are quite happy with me since having this many papers at that conference was unseen before. They just let me do my own thing and trust that my desire for quality will result in great work.

So I'm near the end of my phd. I still really enjoy research but I'm doubting if the whole research community is giving everyone an equal chance. It seems as if it is governed by a group of great researchers from top universities who don't want to get involved with other smaller universities and it almost seems as if they blame me for being at a university that is less known. Let me try to give some examples. Since I attended and presented at some conferences (where I presented my papers), I start to know people and they start to know me and we briefly talk but it seems as if it stops there. They congratulate me with the great presentation and work and next year they publish something very similar but do not refer to my work. Somehow they get away with it (probably because their papers are indeed very good and a paper will not be rejected because of 1 missing reference of a research group, the reviewers are maybe not even aware). So as a result, my papers do not get a lot of citations. I do get some requests to review papers for decent conferences but I still get all the crappy papers that are "easy rejects".

In contrast, I see phd students from top universities working with well-known researchers who are on exactly the same track as me (similar number of papers at same conference) and their papers get a huge amount of citations, they are invited to visit other research labs, are already involved as organizers in these conferences,... This is probably just because more people know there well known advisor, visit their website more often and spot the new work with their phd students.

Since many of these people have the same age and are interested in the same stuff as me, we talk fairly often and they are almost friends. When I talk to more senior people at conferences, oftentimes, they start to ask which university I'm from and who I work with. Then they react quite strange when I answer, it gets awkward and we stop talking.

So now I'm near the end of my phd and despite the papers that I have my h-index is quite low, my network not so big and my recommendation letters probably do not have same value as the once from other universities. I feel that I didn't get as many opportunities as other researchers with the same qualifications. Too me it seems as if I pay a big price for not being at a top university whereas I always thought that in science only the quality of your results mattered. I really enjoy doing research and I will probably find some position somewhere.  But I feel quite depressed about this.

Anyone who has similar experiences or advice? Do you have to be at a highly reputable university to make true progress in academia? I dont think this is in line with what science ought to be.

Comment: to me your question sounds more like a rant, especially with the current title.  I would suggest changing the title to what i think your real question is, is being at a highly reputable university the only way to progress in academia.  Similar questions on academiaSe may give you some insight, such as the number of professors at high ranked schools that are not from high ranked schools

Comment: Sorry for that. I updated it

Comment: _they are invited to visit other research labs_ — Just to pick out one point here.  The way you get invitation to other research labs is by **inviting yourself** to other research labs.  It seems nobody in your department is networking on your behalf; unfortunately, that means you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I am not voting to reopen, because I don't see an actual question in the body of the post.

Comment: thanks for the replies. I made it more specific in the end.

Comment: Thanks JeffE, Do some advisors network on behalf of their students. E.g. arrange visits, talks?